# Is it possible to do keystroke broadcasting across a LAN on a Macintosh?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hotkeys, broadcast

I have done the keystroke broadcasting in Windows like if I press any key in one PC the same key will be broadcast to another PC on the LAN. I wonder if there is anyway to use the same technique on a Macintosh as well?

Comment: what are you trying to do?  Control another computer remotely?  Or just arbitrarily spit keystrokes at another machine?

Comment: I am just trying to arbitrarily spit keystrokes to another machine.@Russell